# Permissions denied to override or delete node targets

Tags: npm, osx-yosemite

I've been running into an issue where every time I've attempted to run an npm install command I receive an error: '-bash: npm: command not found'
So I've attempted to uninstall and reinstall both node and npm using homebrew, but still running into a few errors. After I've uninstalled both, I have run the command: "brew doctor" and I get "Your system is ready to brew."

First I attempt to install node: "brew install node", but I get the following:

```
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/node-

0.12.7.yosemite.bottle
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/node-0.12.7.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring node-0.12.7.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats

Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
Target /usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite node

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run node

Possible conflicting files are:
/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
/usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall node`
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.12.7: 2726 files, 31M
Jamess-MacBook-Pro:~ jamesbradley$
```

So then I attempt to remove the target:

```
Jamess-MacBook-Pro:~ jamesbradley$ rm 
'/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp'
override rw-r--r--  root/admin for /usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp? y
rm: /usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp: Permission denied
Jamess-MacBook-Pro:~ jamesbradley$
```

and I get the following:

```
rm: /usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp: Permission denied
```

so then I attempt to override and I get this error:

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.12.7... 
Error: Could not symlink share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset is not writable.
Jamess-MacBook-Pro:~ jamesbradley$
```

I've also attempted to brew postinstall node and I get this response:

```
Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
Jamess-MacBook-Pro:~ jamesbradley$
```

I've also attempted to run a number of other commands:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /Library/Caches/Homebrew/
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup
```

but nothing seems to be working.

Does anyone know how I can obtain permissions to delete and/or how to make these files writable so I can either overwrite or delete them?

Answer (score 15):

Remove the folder

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/systemtap/
```

Remove all the node installed previously if you want.

```
brew uninstall node
```

Then reinstall node

```
brew install node
```

I had the same issue, worked for me.